How to integrate ST7789 display driver in ESP32 using ESP-IDF
I am trying to integrate ST7789 based display module with my ESP32 using ESP-IDF
Here is a clear picture of display


code is not proceeding after lv_st7789_create function
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <esp_timer.h>
#include <esp_log.h>

#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_freertos_hooks.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/spi_master.h"

#include "lvgl.h"
#include "lvgl__lvgl/src/drivers/display/st7789/lv_st7789.h"

#define LCD_HOST VSPI_HOST

#define PIN_NUM_MISO -1
#define PIN_NUM_MOSI 23
#define PIN_NUM_CLK  19
#define PIN_NUM_CS   -1

#define PIN_NUM_DC   21
#define PIN_NUM_RST  18
#define PIN_NUM_BCKL 5

#define LCD_H_RES               240
#define LCD_V_RES               240
#define LCD_BUF_LINES   60

#define LV_TICK_PERIOD_MS 1

static void lv_tick_task(void *arg);

static void guiTask(void *pvParameter);

static void create_demo_application(void);

lv_display_t *my_disp;

spi_device_handle_t spi;

void lcd_init() {
    gpio_config_t io_conf = {};
    io_conf.pin_bit_mask = ((1ULL << PIN_NUM_DC) | (1ULL << PIN_NUM_RST) | (1ULL << PIN_NUM_BCKL));
    io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
    io_conf.pull_up_en = true;
    gpio_config(&io_conf);

    gpio_set_level(PIN_NUM_RST, 0);
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    gpio_set_level(PIN_NUM_RST, 1);
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    gpio_set_level(PIN_NUM_DC, 0);
//    gpio_set_level(PIN_NUM_CS, 0);
    gpio_set_level(PIN_NUM_BCKL, 1);
}

void init_spi() {
    spi_bus_config_t bus_cfg = {
            .mosi_io_num = PIN_NUM_MOSI,
            .miso_io_num = PIN_NUM_MISO,
            .sclk_io_num = PIN_NUM_CLK,
            .quadwp_io_num = -1,
            .quadhd_io_num = -1,
            .max_transfer_sz = LCD_BUF_LINES * LCD_H_RES + 8,
    };
    spi_device_interface_config_t dev_cfg = {
            .mode = 0,
            .clock_speed_hz = 10 * 1000 * 1000,
            .spics_io_num = PIN_NUM_CS,
            .queue_size = 7,
    };
    esp_err_t ret = spi_bus_initialize(LCD_HOST, &bus_cfg, SPI_DMA_CH_AUTO);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ret);

    ret = spi_bus_add_device(LCD_HOST, &dev_cfg, &spi);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ret);
}

void my_lcd_send_cmd(lv_display_t *disp, const uint8_t *cmd, size_t cmd_size, const uint8_t *param, size_t param_size) {
    esp_err_t ret;

    spi_transaction_t t;
    memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
    t.length = cmd_size * 8;
    t.tx_buffer = cmd;
    t.user = (void *) 0;

    ret = spi_device_transmit(spi, &t);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE("lcd_send_cmd", "Error transmitting command: %d", ret);
        return;
    }

    if (param_size > 0) {
        t.length = param_size * 8; // Length of parameters
        t.tx_buffer = param;
        t.user = (void *) 1; // Data

        ret = spi_device_transmit(spi, &t);
        if (ret != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE("lcd_send_cmd", "Error transmitting data: %d", ret);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void my_lcd_send_color(lv_display_t *disp, const uint8_t *cmd, size_t cmd_size, uint8_t *param, size_t param_size) {
    esp_err_t ret;

    spi_transaction_t t;
    memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
    t.length = cmd_size * 8;
    t.tx_buffer = cmd;
    t.user = (void *) 0;
    t.flags = SPI_TRANS_CS_KEEP_ACTIVE;

    ret = spi_device_transmit(spi, &t);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE("lcd_send_color", "Error transmitting command: %d", ret);
        return;
    }

    if (param_size > 0) {
        t.length = param_size * 8; // Length of color data
        t.tx_buffer = param;
        t.user = (void *) 1; // Data

        ret = spi_device_transmit(spi, &t);
        if (ret != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE("lcd_send_color", "Error transmitting color data: %d", ret);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void app_main(void) {
    lcd_init();

    init_spi();

    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(guiTask, "gui", 4096 * 2, NULL, 0, NULL, 1);
}

SemaphoreHandle_t xGuiSemaphore;

static void guiTask(void *pvParameter) {
    (void) pvParameter;
    xGuiSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    lv_init();
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));

    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    my_disp = lv_st7789_create(LCD_H_RES, LCD_V_RES, 0, my_lcd_send_cmd, my_lcd_send_color);
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);

    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    lv_display_set_rotation(my_disp, LV_DISPLAY_ROTATION_0);
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);

    lv_color_t *buf1 = NULL;
    lv_color_t *buf2 = NULL;

    uint32_t buf_size = LCD_H_RES * LCD_V_RES / 10 * lv_color_format_get_size(lv_display_get_color_format(my_disp));

    buf1 = lv_malloc(buf_size);
    if (buf1 == NULL) {
        LV_LOG_ERROR("display draw buffer malloc failed");
        return;
    }

    buf2 = lv_malloc(buf_size);
    if (buf2 == NULL) {
        LV_LOG_ERROR("display buffer malloc failed");
        lv_free(buf1);
        return;
    }
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    lv_display_set_buffers(my_disp, buf1, buf2, buf_size, LV_DISPLAY_RENDER_MODE_PARTIAL);
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    /* Create and start a periodic timer interrupt to call lv_tick_inc */
    const esp_timer_create_args_t periodic_timer_args = {
            .callback = &lv_tick_task,
            .name = "periodic_gui"
    };

    esp_timer_handle_t periodic_timer;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_timer_create(&periodic_timer_args, &periodic_timer));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_timer_start_periodic(periodic_timer, LV_TICK_PERIOD_MS * 1000));

    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    create_demo_application();
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);

    while (1) {
        /* Delay 1 tick (assumes FreeRTOS tick is 10ms */
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));

        /* Try to take the semaphore, call lvgl related function on success */
        if (pdTRUE == xSemaphoreTake(xGuiSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY)) {
            lv_task_handler();
            xSemaphoreGive(xGuiSemaphore);
        }
    }

    /* A task should NEVER return */
    free(buf1);

    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

static void create_demo_application(void) {
    lv_obj_t *obj;

    /* set screen background to white */
    lv_obj_t *scr = lv_screen_active();
    lv_obj_set_style_bg_color(scr, lv_color_white(), 0);
    lv_obj_set_style_bg_opa(scr, LV_OPA_100, 0);

    /* create label */
    obj = lv_label_create(scr);
    lv_obj_set_align(obj, LV_ALIGN_CENTER);
    lv_obj_set_height(obj, LV_SIZE_CONTENT);
    lv_obj_set_width(obj, LV_SIZE_CONTENT);
    lv_obj_set_style_text_font(obj, &lv_font_montserrat_14, 0);
    lv_obj_set_style_text_color(obj, lv_color_black(), 0);
    lv_label_set_text(obj, "Hello World!");
}

static void lv_tick_task(void *arg) {
    (void) arg;

    lv_tick_inc(LV_TICK_PERIOD_MS);
}

This is the output of the program
I (286) cpu_start: Project name:     hello_world
I (292) cpu_start: App version:      1
I (296) cpu_start: Compile time:     Apr  9 2024 23:41:21
I (302) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  dd8b0cf88...
I (307) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v5.2-dirty
I (313) cpu_start: Min chip rev:     v0.0
I (317) cpu_start: Max chip rev:     v3.99 
I (322) cpu_start: Chip rev:         v3.0
I (327) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (334) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM
I (340) heap_init: At 3FFC2EC0 len 0001D140 (116 KiB): DRAM
I (346) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (353) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (359) heap_init: At 4008E224 len 00011DDC (71 KiB): IRAM
I (367) spi_flash: detected chip: generic
I (370) spi_flash: flash io: dio
W (374) spi_flash: Detected size(4096k) larger than the size in the binary image header(2048k). Using the size in the binary image header.
I (388) main_task: Started on CPU0
I (398) main_task: Calling app_main()
I (398) gpio: GPIO[5]| InputEn: 0| OutputEn: 1| OpenDrain: 0| Pullup: 1| Pulldown: 0| Intr:0 
I (398) gpio: GPIO[18]| InputEn: 0| OutputEn: 1| OpenDrain: 0| Pullup: 1| Pulldown: 0| Intr:0 
I (408) gpio: GPIO[21]| InputEn: 0| OutputEn: 1| OpenDrain: 0| Pullup: 1| Pulldown: 0| Intr:0 
I (618) main_task: Returned from app_main()
156
158
161

and the Display is blank
Please help me
Where I am doing wrong?
Is there any easy way to integrate ST7789 display into ESP32 using ESP-IDF

ESP-IDF, ESP32, ST7789, and LVGL are an extremely common combination. GitHub has many examples of this working.
You didn't include analyzer dumps showing what was on the SPI bus, confirmed that the wiring hookups matched the code, the options you chose in menuconfig, your serious attempts at debugging the code (step into the hanging function, confirm that timer tasks are running, etc.), or confirmed that other, known working, projects work on your hardware so we can guess if it's code or wiring, so it's a pretty unrealistic question to expect help on it. Perhaps someone will make a lucky guess, but I'll try to steer you to known working examples.
To get you going in a forward direction, please review code like:
https://docs.lvgl.io/master/integration/chip/espressif.html - LVGL's own doc and code. Uses https://github.com/lvgl/lv_port_esp32 has a main.c that's of similar complexity to the above.
https://github.com/Omegaki113r/lvgl_demo is similarly simple
https://github.com/lbthomsen/esp-idf-littlevgl builds upon https://github.com/lbthomsen/esp-idf-littlevgl-demo
There are a LOT of simpler 7789 + ESP32 + LVGL projects out there. Take working code, get it going on your hardware, and build up from there.
